# Converting relationship data from row into columns per parent ID

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a parent-child kind of relationship data, where I need to list all children in its own columns with the parent as the primary key.

The number of child per parent is not a set number of child element, it may vary.

```
 Relationship Datset

 pID        CID
----       ------
1001       abc
1001       xyz
1001       srt
1001       unc
1002       sfds
1002       werew
1002       cbvcb
1002       asds
1003       uiop
1003       qaxz
1004       ujnb
1005       loda
1005       pols

Query Resultexpected:

pID     CID_1      CID_2       CID_3      CID_4          CID_5
--      -------    -------     -------    -------        -------
1001     abc       xyz         srt        unc            NULL
1002     sfds      werew       cbvcb      asds           NULL
1003     uiop      qaxz        NULL       NULL           NULL
1004     ujnb      NULL        NULL       NULL           NULL
1005     loda      pols        NULL       NULL           NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be much easier if you do in python. 
- create array of map/dictionary. 
- Then read through each row. 
- Check if it any array contain info that have same pID.
- If it match, push it to that element.
   else create the next element with that pID and push to array.